# Docker to run new container - list of all mapped ports?

Tags: docker, port

When running a new container, we specify a port `RUN_PORT:EXPOSED_PORT` to map with the host machine. This will fail if `RUN_PORT` is already used.

So my question is how to list all the mapped port - so that we can pick up the port number out of the list.

p.s.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Assuming you're on Ubuntu. I would do `sudo netstat -alnp  | grep LISTEN` to check and see if the port I want to use is taken or not. If it is taken, can I terminate the program to free it up? if no then I typically move on to another port.

Comment: Yeah, Ubuntu it is. Sound a right solution though the printed output is noisy though - great if you would make it just the list of used port and post as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following command

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep ":RUN_PORT"
```

Replace RUN_PORT with the actual port to see which application is blocking it.

Comment: What a clever way <3

Comment: Though I got lots of ports occupied on my server which run Docker; would love to be able to get the clean list of occupied ports.

Comment: Then use the command stated in the comments above. Otherwise you have to look for an application that displays occupied ports in a proper GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Listing all tcp ports being used (for listening) can be seen with:

```
netstat -lnt
```

Looking up what is using a single port can be done with a netstat and grep, or if you have lsof installed:

```
sudo lsof -i :80 # shows the process using port 80
```

Starting a docker container on a random available port mapped to port 80 inside the container:

```
docker run -p 80 -n container_name your_container
```

Looking up what random port docker used in the above command on the host (this includes what IP interfaces it's attached to, or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces, which is the default):

```
docker port container_name 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the random port idea. Though we need to set specific port by our own.